# mySQL query gives syntax error in java, but works fine in mySQL workbench

Tags: java, mysql, syntax, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to execute the sql query:

```
INSERT INTO celebrity (name, `1`, `15`, `3`, `20`, `4`, `13`, `35`, `22`, `6`, `19`) VALUES ("Keith Allen", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1)
```

which worked fine in the workbench and correctly added the new row, however when I call the same query from java using the executeUpdate(String query) method, I get a sql syntax error

Comment: can you try `'Keith Allen'`

Comment: The ` character is there so sql can tell that `1` is the name of a column and not just an integer. I was using ' before and I was getting syntax errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your double quotes like this:

```
INSERT INTO celebrity (name, `1`, `15`, `3`, `20`, `4`, `13`, `35`, `22`, `6`, `19`)
VALUES (\"Keith Allen\", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1)
```